# page freeze when div updated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have recently added a javascript that does the collapse function for the faq page
my page is a scrolling page using javascript aswell
but the problem is when the collapse javascript runs ex:click on question and answer appears
the page freezes and i can no longer scroll i dont know why

here is the website http://sheetmulching.com/sr/examples/backgroundsFixed.html

and here is the javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
$('.togglefaq').click(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();
var notthis = $('.active').not(this);
notthis.find('.icon-remove ').addClass('icon-plus').removeClass('icon-remove ');
notthis.toggleClass('active').next('.faqanswer').slideToggle(300);
 $(this).toggleClass('active').next().slideToggle("fast");
$(this).children('i').toggleClass('icon-plus icon-remove ');
});
})
```

whats the solution for the scroll freeze?

Comment: Would this website by any chance be selling services that break Blizzards terms of use policies?

Comment: no its just information @Brad

Comment: I'm not able to test it, but have you try removing e.preventDefault() ?

Comment: yea i tried but still doesnt work @SergioAMG

Answer (score 0):

Apparently something is with your scrolloverflow.js file - when you execute the function it stops functioning, it has nothing to do with changing css, I checked that. So maybe you should start there.

Comment: i checked  it before but dunno the problem